# AngularJS v1.4 function call from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I need to call an AngularJS function call from javascript-side.

The below is the function I want to call from javascript.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-iot-examples/blob/master/mqttSample/js/app.js

```
AppController.$inject = ['$scope'];
AppController.prototype.createClient = function() {

    var options = {
      clientId : this.clientId,
      endpoint: this.endpoint.toLowerCase(),
      accessKey: this.accessKey,
      secretKey: this.secretKey,
      regionName: this.regionName
    };
    var client = this.clients.getClient(options);
    if (!client.connected) {
      client.connect(options);
    }
};
```

My javascript

```
<body>
    <div id='myid' class="container" ng-app="awsiot.sample" ng-controller="AppController as vm">
  ....
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id='myclick' ng-click="vm.createClient()" >Create Client</button>  <-- working! -->      
  </div>  

....

<script>
  angular.element('#myid').scope().createClient(); // not working!
</script>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Based on script tag shown you might be calling that before angular has even compiled the controller and the dom. Any errors in console?

Comment: Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by `angular.element`. Also controller scope is created during the AngularJS run phase which occurs well after [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish here? Maybe there is a better way than calling a controller function from outside the AngularJS framework.

Comment: @georgeawg To call createClient() in angular is what I want to accomplish :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myid')).controller().info();
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-wxjhgd
you can tweak it to suit your needs

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: I already included the essential part ... Other parts are straightforward :)

Comment: Thanks ABOS I tried but the result is,

(index):117 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'info' of undefined
    at (index):117
(anonymous) @ (index):117

Answer (score 0):

> To call createClient() in angular is what I want to accomplish

Put the call in the `$onInit` function of the controller:

```
function AppController() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
        this.createClient();
    });
}
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $compile Service API Reference - Life-Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).